# Nesting a Wordpress function within a shortcode within a function

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I need to use a plugin shortcode within a template file, but have one of the variables be set by the value of a custom field in the post. Here's what I have so far. This just breaks the entire page.

My effort (not working):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpsp pls_id="get_post_meta($post->ID, 'playlist', true)"]'); ?>
```

The shortcode:

```
[wpsp pls_id="NEED VALUE SET HERE"]
```

The custom field function:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'playlist', true); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This might work out well for you:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209684/passing-attributes-to-shortcode-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpsp pls_id="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'playlist', true) . '"]'); ?>
```